# finding eigenvectors only knowing the eigenvalues and not the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Was just curious, is it possible to obtain the eigenvectors if you only know the eigenvalues and the dimensions of a square matrix? Or what further information from the matrix can you gain from only knowing the eigenvalues?

Comment: Eigenvectors are the nontrivial solutions of $(\lambda I -A)x=0$ (i.e. the set of all solutions is the null space of the matrix $(\lambda I -A)$). You need both the matrix and the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not. Given the eigenvalues, you can choose your eigenvectors arbitrarily. In the basis of those eigenvectors, your transformation will have diagonal form with the given eigenvalues on the diagonal. Of course, in any given fixed basis, the corresponding matrices will be very different.

Knowing the eigenvalues, some invariants are fully determined like the determinant and the trace. Not the eigenvectors though.